# How can I make an interactive matplotlib legend such that I can remove lines from my plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, tkinter

Ideally would like to implement this with crosses next to legend labels that can be clicked to remove the line from the plot. Right now I am trying to do this simply by clicking on the legend entry's line to delete the graph from the plot; I'm doing this by way of a dictionary mapping the legend entry to the line on the plot. The issue I'm having is that whenever more than one line is added to the plot, I can remove all lines except the first one plotted.  I suspect this issue may be due to me re-creating the legend, which may be messing with the dictionary mappings.

Initializing the plot in the class init method as such,

```
f = Figure(figsize=(1, 1), dpi=100)
self.chart = f.add_subplot(111)
self.lined = dict()
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
self.canvas.draw()
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.remove_graph)
```

And these are the functions pertaining to plotting lines and removing them.

```
def plot_prices(self, event=None):
    ticker = self.entry.get().upper()
    with open(suffixed_ticker_dump_path, 'rb') as tickers:
        tickers = pickle.load(tickers)
        if ticker not in tickers:
            self.popupmsg("Invalid ticker input. Enter a valid ticker.")
        else:
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(daily_data_dir, '{}.csv'.format(ticker)),
                             index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
            prices = df['adjusted_close'].replace(0, np.nan)
            line,=self.chart.plot(prices.interpolate(), label=ticker)

            self.leg = self.chart.legend(loc='lower right')
            legline = self.leg.get_lines()[-1]
            legline.set_picker(5)
            self.lined[legline] = line

            self.canvas.draw()

def remove_graph(self, event=None):
    legline = event.artist
    origline = self.lined[legline]
    origline.remove()
    self.leg = self.chart.legend(loc='lower right')
    self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: In how far is [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/event_handling/legend_picking.html) not what you're trying to do? (Note that with incomplete codes, it's really hard to help.)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Instead of toggling visibility, I'd like to fully remove a line from the plot (i.e. delete it).

Comment: It *looks* like this is what your code does. But because it's not runnable I cannot find out why it would fail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up fixing the problem by simply clearing and resetting the dictionary mapping legend entries to lines on the chart after either plotting a line or removing one. I imagine it didnt work before due to some techinicality with the references to the lines being different in the legend and the chart, unless somebody has a better solution I'll use this as it isn't much extra code.

```
def plot_prices(self, event=None):
    ticker = self.entry.get().upper()
    with open(suffixed_ticker_dump_path, 'rb') as tickers:
        tickers = pickle.load(tickers)
        if ticker not in tickers:
            self.popupmsg("Invalid ticker input. Enter a valid ticker.")
        else:
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(daily_data_dir, '{}.csv'.format(ticker)),
                             index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
            prices = df['adjusted_close'].replace(0, np.nan)
            line,=self.chart.plot(prices.interpolate(), label=ticker)
            self.leg = self.chart.legend(loc='lower right')
            self.reset_line_dict()
            self.canvas.draw()

def remove_graph(self, event=None):
    legline = event.artist
    origline = self.lined[legline]
    self.chart.lines.remove(origline)
    self.leg = self.chart.legend(loc='lower right')
    self.reset_line_dict()
    self.canvas.draw()

def reset_line_dict(self):
    self.lined.clear()
    for legline, origline in zip(self.leg.get_lines(), self.chart.get_lines()):
        legline.set_picker(5)  # 5 pts tolerance
        self.lined[legline] = origline
```